# Accessing attributtes of an object in the browser with parent key

Tags: django, django-views

```
def detail(request,x_id):
    try:
        album = X.objects.get(pk=x_id)

    except X.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("X Does NOt Exist")
    return render(request, 'abc/abc.html', {'x':x})
```

When I try to access it on the browser it just shows x object. Not the attributes it has.

abc.html has just this:
    {{x}}

Comment: Which attributes do you want to show?

Comment: THere are a bunch of inputs a gave to X via database shell command.  Want to show these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access atribute of `x` object you have to write `x.object_atribute` in your `html` file. So for example if you send `book object` to your html that has `author`, `title` attributes you have to write something like:

`<ul>
  <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
  <li>{{ book.author }}</li>
</ul>`